# TRIM is not working

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I don't understand why, but my implementation of the TRIM keyword is not TRIMming spaces ... here is the code i've tried:

```
    SQL> 
    SQL> select ltrim('WebService Access Time'||null),rtrim(min(response_time)),rtrim(max(response_time)),rtrim(avg(response_time)) from myuser.access_log where access_date between to_date('2017/11/20','yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('2017/11/26','yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss');
    WebService Access Time,3                                       ,40914                                   ,35.8903038316018836644721402687804875597
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> select ltrim('WebService Access Time'||null),min(response_time),max(response_time),avg(response_time) from myuser.access_log where access_date between to_date('2017/11/20','yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('2017/11/26','yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss');
    WebService Access Time,                 3,             40914,        35.8903038
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> select trim(both from 'WebService Access Time'||null),trim(both from min(response_time)),trim(both from max(response_time)),trim(both from avg(response_time)) from myuser.access_log where access_date between to_date('2017/11/20','yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('2017/11/26','yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss');
    WebService Access Time,3                                       ,40914                                   ,35.8903038316018836644721402687804875597
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> select trim(both ' ' from 'WebService Access Time'||null),trim(both ' ' from min(response_time)),trim(both ' ' from max(response_time)),trim(both ' ' from avg(response_time)) from myuser.access_log where access_date between to_date('2017/11/20','yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('2017/11/26','yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss');
    WebService Access Time,3                                       ,40914                                   ,35.8903038316018836644721402687804875597
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> select '>'|| trim ('      removing spaces at both ends      ') ||'<' "Spaces Removed" from dual;
    >removing spaces at both ends<
    SQL> select '>'|| trim('      removing spaces at both ends      ') ||'<' "Spaces Removed" from dual;
    >removing spaces at both ends<
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> select 'WebService Access Time'||null,trim(min(response_time)),trim(max(response_time)),trim(avg(response_time)) from myuser.access_log where access_date between to_date('2017/11/20','yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('2017/11/26','yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss');
    WebService Access Time,3                                       ,40914                                   ,35.8903038316018836644721402687804875597
```

As you can see, I've been playing with examples from different tutorials, trying to get it to work -- and nothing seems to be working ... I'm not getting any SQL Errors, so I assume the syntax is right, but clearly, I'm missing something!

Please help!

This work is being performed via SQLPlus, **no GUI client is available**.

***Note: Assume I am a non-privileged user, with GRANTS for only SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT.***

[Here is an image of the code too ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bousg.png)

Comment: I don't understand what "undesired behavior" you are reporting. The fact that in the OUTPUT, the `min(response_time)` values appear to take too much space (to be padded with spaces you can't seem to remove)? This is a feature of SQL\*Plus, not a SQL issue! You need to format the output columns using the SQL\*Plus `COLUMN` command.

Comment: Given that your question is entirely about rendering the output of a query the least you could have done is format your question so that the query you're running and its output are readable. You want us to spend our time helping you but you won't invest your time in framing the question.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call trim on each expression (I've also aliased the columns):

```
select
   'WebService Access Time' description,
   trim(min(response_time)) min_response_time,
   trim(max(response_time)) max_response_time,
   trim(avg(response_time)) avg_repsonse_time
from
    myuser.access_log
where
    access_date between
    to_date('2017/11/20','yyyy/mm/dd')
    and
    to_date('2017/11/26','yyyy/mm/dd');
```